# Delete a column in a log, that changes position in the line, Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, replace

I have a log file, and I want to get rid of the third column that start with "external", this column is not always in the third place so I need to find the word "external" and then delete it with the string that follows the colon.

I was thinking in using -replace for that, but does "-replace" accept some regex to delete the rest of the string (after the semicolons) that is always changing?

or maybe there is a better way to do this?

```
02/02/2020  name:VAL_NATURE external:af2045b2-5992-432e-b790-c1ad4743038 status:good
```

```
cat mylog.log | %{$_ -replace "external???",""}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any delimited file, the first thought I have is to break it at the delimiters (in your case, the white space) and treat it like an object.  Deleting a column is trivial if you do that, and it lets you have easy access to the data for other purposes.

If, however, your only task is to remove that column with 'external' + colon + all text up to the next bit of white space, that is an easy thing to do with a regex replace.

```
$line = '02/02/2020  name:VAL_NATURE external:af2045b2-5992-432e-b790-c1ad4743038 status:good'
$line -replace 'external:.*\s',''
```

EDIT: Tested the code above, and got this output:

```
02/02/2020  name:VAL_NATURE status:good
```

The `.` is any character, and `.*` says "any character zero or more times" it continues matching until it gets to whitespace, which is represented by the `\s`.  So this regex matches the word 'external' followed by a ':' followed by zero or more other characters followed by whitespace (space/tab/etc).

Comment: thanks, It works, but it keep deleting the other values to the right in the log lines, its weird beacause "\s" will match any white space, so in the case that is a space or tab shouldn matter

Comment: Well, the one line of test data you gave us to work with gave me the right answer.  See my edit above.  If you have other lines which do not function properly with my suggestion, feel free to post them.

Comment: Based on your answer, I end up using this: cat mylog.log | %{$_ -replace "external:([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\s",""}

Comment: Ok, that looks really good @ElonMollusk.  Glad it was able to steer you in the right direction!